# wpf получить sourse картинки которая находится в listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, listbox

Есть `ListBox`, который содержит картинки, как получить по нажатию на `ListItem` ресурс изображения, которое он содержит?

Comment: Приведите хоть какой-то код, как вы заполняете listBox, какими значениями и т. д.

Comment: уже решил,можете глянуть

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться извлечь информацию из View. Вы должны использовать MVVM для такого.

Comment: Знаю, но если нет времени переносить на mvvm то и так можно

Answer (score 1):

Все изи, вот написал код который вызывается для drag and drop в wpf. Картинки из Listbox дропаются в border содержащий image

```
  private void GetImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = (Image)sender;
        var data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void Image_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }         
    private void SelectItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;
        var  selectedItem = (Image)lst.SelectedItem;
        Image image=new Image();
        image.Source=selectedItem.Source;
        var data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

ну и xaml соответственно

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="504,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128"/>
    <Button Content="Назад" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,385,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Height="36" Click="BackPage"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="ClothList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="368" Margin="18,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="SelectItem" />
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropImage" Margin="250,26,378,286">
            <Image Margin="9"/>
        </Border>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropImage" Margin="250,144,378,168">
        <Image Margin="9,-1,9,9" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,0.5"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

сам listbox заполняется из базы данных

```
 CClothContext db = new CClothContext();
        var ClList = db.Clothe.ToList();
        foreach (var num in ClList)
        {
           Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = byteArrayToImage(num.Cloth_img).Source;
            ClothList.Items.Add(img);
        }
```